# Android Listener pattern vs Callback pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns, okhttp

When I'm working on networking functions in OkHttp, there are mainly 2 patterns I come across with:

1. Listener pattern
2. Callback pattern

**Listener Pattern example:**

```
// Listener class
public interface NetworkListener {
    void onFailure(Request request, IOException e);
    void onResponse(Response response);
}

// NetworkManager class
public class NetworkManager {
    static String TAG = "NetworkManager";
    public NetworkListener listener;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    public void setListener(NetworkListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    void post(String url, JSONObject json) throws IOException {
        //RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        try {
            JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("d");
            RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                    .add("m", json.getString("m"))
                    .add("d", array.toString())
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            // Asynchronous Mode
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    if(listener != null) {
                        listener.onFailure(request, e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    Log.w(TAG, response.body().string());
                    if(listener != null) {
                        listener.onResponse(response);
                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException jsone) {
            Log.e(TAG, jsone.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

// In the Activity
NetworkManager manager = new NetworkManager();
manager.setListener(this);
try {
  requestState = RequestState.REQUESTING;
  manager.post("http://www.example.com/api.php", reqObj);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
  Log.e(TAG, ioe.getMessage());
}
```

**Callback Pattern example:**

```
// in onCreate
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        doGET(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.d("OkHttp", "Shit happens");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String strResponse = response.body().string();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Wrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(strResponse, Wrapper.class);
                    Log.d("OkHttp", wrapper.getListContents());
                } else {
                    Log.d("OkHttp", "Request not successful");
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


Call doGET(Callback callback) throws IOException {
    // Start Network Request
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://www.example.com/api.php").build();
    Call call  = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(callback);
    return call;
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using the 2 patterns above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, they are not different, actually you can find that `Callback` is also an interface.

```
package com.squareup.okhttp;

import java.io.IOException;

public interface Callback {
  /**
   * Called when the request could not be executed due to cancellation, a
   * connectivity problem or timeout. Because networks can fail during an
   * exchange, it is possible that the remote server accepted the request
   * before the failure.
   */
  void onFailure(Request request, IOException e);

  /**
   * Called when the HTTP response was successfully returned by the remote
   * server. The callback may proceed to read the response body with {@link
   * Response#body}. The response is still live until its response body is
   * closed with {@code response.body().close()}. The recipient of the callback
   * may even consume the response body on another thread.
   *
   * <p>Note that transport-layer success (receiving a HTTP response code,
   * headers and body) does not necessarily indicate application-layer
   * success: {@code response} may still indicate an unhappy HTTP response
   * code like 404 or 500.
   */
  void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException;
}
```

However, when I want to reuse some codes (or build an util class), I often use as the following:

Interface:

```
public interface OkHttpListener {
    void onFailure(Request request, IOException e);
    void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException;
}
```

Util class:

```
public class OkHttpUtils {
    public static void getData(String url, final OkHttpListener listener){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        // GET request
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                listener.onFailure(request, e);
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                listener.onResponse(response);
            }
        });
    }


// the following uses built-in okhttp's Callback interface
    public static void getData2(String url, Callback callbackListener){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        // GET request
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callbackListener);
    }
    // other methods...
}
```

Then in activity classes:

```
       OkHttpListener listener = new OkHttpListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                String responseBody = response.body().string();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, responseBody);
            }
        };
        String url = "http://myserver/api/getvalues";
        OkHttpUtils.getData(url, listener);
        String url1 = "http://myserver/api/getvalues/123";
        OkHttpUtils.getData(url1, listener);
```

or

```
       Callback callbackListener = new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                String responseBody = response.body().string();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, responseBody);
            }
        };

        String url = "http://myserver/api/getvalues";
        OkHttpUtils.getData2(url, callbackListener);
        String url1 = "http://myserver/api/getvalues/123";
        OkHttpUtils.getData2(url1, callbackListener);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Can I conclude that Callback is just a wrapper of Listener, which Callback is preferred, as it simplifies the coding?

Comment: I think `Callback` or `Listener` is just a name, both of them are `interface`

Comment: @BNK A little nitpick: don't forget to close your `ResponseBody` when you are done with it.

Comment: @EricCochran thanks for your comment, the above is just a basic case :). Anyway, do you mean that don't call "response.body().string();" twice or more?

Comment: @BNK I mean calling [`ResponseBody.close()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/ResponseBody.html#close--).

Comment: @EricCochran I have not ever used it before. IMO, after "response.body().string();" called, it is closed already.

Comment: @BNK `string()` does not close the underlying reader to free the resources.

Comment: @EricCochran: I have checked, since `string()` calls `bytes()`, then inside `bytes()`, `Util.closeQuietly(source);`  called, `source` is a BufferedSource. Inside `closeQuietly`, `closeable.close();` called. Does `closeable.close();` not free the resources? Could you explain that? Thanks

Comment: @BNK Yep, you are very right. `bytes()` will close. My bad! Thanks for the correction!